# Running into errors allocating connections

Tags: glassfish, jms, openmq

My environment is Glassfish 3.1.2 b23 with the bundled OpenMQ in embedded mode (and FWIW I've also tried LOCAL mode w/the same results) on Windows Server 2008 with JDK 1.7.0_45.

I have an application which contains a very simple JMS component.  The JMS component is composed of a stateless session bean which produces messages that are sent to a Queue and consumed by a MDB. The JMS connection pool and Queue are administered objected created using the Glassfish administration UI.

The problem is that after some time of creating and consuming messages normally the following error appears:

```
com.sun.messaging.jms.JMSException: MQRA:DCF:allocation failure:createConnection:Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory._allocateConnection(DirectConnectionFactory.java:548)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory.createConnection(DirectConnectionFactory.java:265)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory.createConnection(DirectConnectionFactory.java:244)
    at 
    [SNIP]
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectConnectionFactory._allocateConnection(DirectConnectionFactory.java:543)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:418)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:301)
    ... 103 more
```

This seems to occur when an automated process which is started by an `@Asynchronous` method of a Stateless EJB rips through a list of items and for each item calls the code path which eventually touches this message production. When the message production is called from a slightly different code path which only generates one message at a time we don't see this problem.

Messages take just ms. to produce and ms. to consume. The max-wait time for a connection is 1 minute. Also the max. number of threads that could be simultaneously producing messages is less (by about a factor of 2) the max number of connections assoicated w/the JMS connection factory.

How quickly can the producer, whose session is non-jms-transactional and AUTO-ACK be called back to back? I would assume that as soon as the producer.send(..) returns that the jms connection would be returned and available for the next producer or is there some very slight lag time before the connection has been freed for the next call to .send()?

The consumer is a MDB which I assume is also using a JMS connection from the same pool the producer is using (as that's the only JMS connection pool). The imqcmd output below indicates there is 1 active consumer, but because MDBs are pooled does that mean the consumer side could be using X # (# of MDB instances) of connections as well or will the MDB just use one connection regardless of the # of pooled MDB instances?

I'm also curious about the exception handling in the MDB. The pattern was taken from the JavaEE6 samples and catches/logs Throwable. Would the lack of call to mdc.setRollback in the Throwable leak JMS connections?

In debugging this issue I have been using the *imqcmd* command. Specifically:

*imqcmd* query dst -t q -n MyQueue -u admin

```
---------------------------------------
Destination Name       Destination Type
---------------------------------------
MyQueue    Queue

On the broker specified by:
-------------------------
Host         Primary Port
-------------------------
localhost    7676

Destination Name                      MyQueue
Destination Type                      Queue
Destination State                     RUNNING
Created Administratively              false

Current Number of Messages
    Actual                            0
    Remote                            0
    Held in Transaction               0
Current Message Bytes
    Actual                            0
    Remote                            0
    Held in Transaction               8928
Current Number of Producers           0
Current Number of Active Consumers    1
Current Number of Backup Consumers    0

Max Number of Messages                100000
Max Total Message Bytes               10737418240
Max Bytes per Message                 10485760
Max Number of Producers               100
Max Number of Active Consumers        unlimited (-1)
Max Number of Backup Consumers        0

Limit Behavior                        REJECT_NEWEST
Consumer Flow Limit                   1000
Is Local Destination                  false
Local Delivery is Preferred           false
Use Dead Message Queue                true
XML schema validation enabled         false
XML schema URI List                   -
Reload XML schema on failure          false

Successfully queried the destination.
```

**Producer: ADetailBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ADetailBean.java {

  private transient static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ADetailBean.java);

  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/MyConnectionFactory")
  private ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;

  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/myApp/MyQueue")
  private javax.jms.Queue myQueue;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPC")
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @EJB
  AnotherBean anotherBean;

  public void createAMessage(@NotNull AFile file, AnAction action) {
    ACollection aCol = aCollectionBean.findReqColForTaskColId(file.getCollectionId());
    if (aCol != null) {
        ADetail aDetail = new ADetail(file.getFileNumber(), file.getCollectionId(), file.getMd5(), reqCol.getCollectionId(), action);
        entityManager.persist(aDetail);
       Connection jmsConnection = null;
        try {
            jmsConnection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = jmsConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(myQueue);
            AMessage aMessage = new AMessage(file.getName());
            ObjectMessage myMessage = session.createObjectMessage(aMessage);
            producer.send(myMessage);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Error sending message for file number: " +
                    file.getFileNumber() + ", md5: " + file.getMd5() +
                    ", action: " + action + " : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (jmsConnection != null) {
                try {
                    jmsConnection.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.warn("Unable to close JMS connection: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

//Other methods in this EJB

}
```

**MDB: MyMessageListener.java**

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/myApp/MyQueue", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability",
                propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId",
                propertyValue = "myClient"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName",
                propertyValue = "mySub")
})
public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyMessageListener.class);

    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPC")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @EJB
    ADetailManager aDetailManager;

    @EJB
    ADetailBean aDetailBean;

    @EJB
    AFileBean aFileBean;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        log.debug("MESSAGE received from the MyQueue queue");
        try {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                if (((ObjectMessage) message).getObject() != null &&
                        ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject() instanceof ACalcMessage) {
                    ACalcMessage msg = (ACalcMessage) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
                    log.debug("MESSAGE BEAN: Received aCalc msg for name: " + msg.getName());
                    //Wait for opportunity to process dupe recalculation for name
                    try {
                        while (!aDetailManager.obtainNameLock(msg.getName())) {
                            log.debug("Waiting to obtain name lock for name: " + msg.getName());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }

                          aDetail aDetail = aDetailBean.findNext(msg.getName());

                          //Do some processing including JPA queries and entity merges

                          entityManager.remove(aDetail);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        aDetailManager.releaseNameLock(msg.getName());
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Error processing message: " + e.getMessage());
            mdc.setRollbackOnly();
        } catch (Throwable te) {
            log.error("Error processing message: ", te);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyConnectionFactory Administered Object Settings**

```
Pool Name: jms/MyConnectionFactory
JNDI Name: jms/MyConnectionFactory
Resource Type: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
Status: [X] Enabled

Initial Minimum Pool Size: 8
Maximum Pool Size: 64
Pool Resize Quantity: 2
Idle Timeout: 300 seconds
Max Wait Time: 60000 Milliseconds
Transaction Support: EMPTY  (I assume this means the default level, which is XA?)
Connection Validation: [X] Required 

No Additional Properties
```

In the connection pool **advanced** tab:

```
Validate At Most Once: 0 Seconds
Leak Timeout: 0 Seconds
Leak Reclaim: [ ]
Creation Retry Attempts: 0
Retry Interval: 10 Seconds
Pooling: [X] Enabled
Lazy Association: [ ] Enabled
Lazy Connection Enlistment: [ ] Enabled
Associate with Thread: [ ] Enabled
Match Connections: [X] Enabled
Max Connection Usage: 0
```

The Queue administered object settings look like so:

```
JNDI Name: jms/myApp/MyQueue
Resource Adapter: jmsra
Resource Type: javax.jms.Queue
Class Name: com.sun.messaging.Queue
Status: [X] Enabled

Additional Properties:
Name   |  Value
----     -------
Name      MyQueue
```